# Exchange 2016 block emails to 2 of specific listed domains

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

We have a requirement to prevent a single email from being sent to more than one of a known list of domains. We basically want to prevent a user from accidentally emailing 2 clients in the same email. These are a known list of domains.

Is this possible in Exchange 2016 or is there a third party offering which may have this functionality?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the email? For example is there some special content in it? Is that a special domain? If yes you could do the following:

1. Try to build a transport [New-TransportRule](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125138(v=exchg.160).aspx)
2. Try to use [Mailflow rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351127(v=exchg.160).aspx)
3. Try to use the [DLP Features in Exchange 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150527(v=exchg.160).aspx)
4. use a 3rd party product e.g. [CodeTwo Exchange Rules Pro](https://www.codetwo.com/blog/email-unsubscribe-mechanism-and-new-dlp-features-new-version-of-codetwo-exchange-rules-pro/?sts=5410)

Comment: Not an answer, OP is looking to allow email to example.com or example.org but not example.com and example.org

Comment: And why shouldn’t that a answer? If it’s a domain he could build a group, throw those users into the group, build a restriction and prevent the members from the group to send to these users/domains?

Comment: I know the list of domains (basically our clients) and it is for all emails. No user on our domain should be able to email any 2 clients in the same email.